# What's the correct interpretation of this byte string?

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, musicbrainz

In a friend's music directory, I came across this path and filename:

```
Ministry/Îšî•Î¦Î‘Î›Î—Îžî˜ (Psalm 69)/Ministry - Îšî•Î¦Î‘Î›Î—Îžî˜ (Psalm 69) - 06 - Scarecrow.mp3
```

You can google `Ministry Îšî•Î¦Î‘Î›Î—Îžî˜` and get results.  If I feed it into a url encoder, I get `%C2%9Ai%C2%95i%C2%A6i%C2%91i%C2%9Bi%C2%97i%C2%9Ei%C2%98`.

It's clearly mangled in some way by traversing multiple incorrect encode/decode cycles.  What is it supposed to be?  How did you get that answer?

I've tried various paper and pencil scribblings with UTF-8, but can't figure out anything that makes sense.

Comment: `ΚΕΦΑΛΗΞΘ`, from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_69:_The_Way_to_Succeed_and_the_Way_to_Suck_Eggs, which I got by putting the recognizable parts into Google.

Answer (score 3):

It is supposed to be `ΚΕΦΑΛΗΞΘ`, which is the title of the Ministry album commonly known as Psalm 69. `ÎšÎ•Î¦Î‘Î›Î—ÎžÎ˜` is what it looks like when the UTF-8 encoded `ΚΕΦΑΛΗΞΘ` is interpreted as Windows-1252.

This is close, but not identical to your `Îšî•Î¦Î‘Î›Î—Îžî˜` which has `î`s in place of two of the `Î`s. My guess for the discrepancies is, given their change and position, somewhere along the way a TitleCase conversion happened as well.

Got there by way of an educated guess, testing, and @Remy's helpful comment.

Comment: The UTF-8 encoded form of `ΚΕΦΑΛΗΞΘ` misinterpreted as Windows-1252 is actually `ÎšÎ•Î¦Î‘Î›Î—ÎžÎ˜` instead, which is close but not identical to what the OP showed. The OP showed `î` in place of 2 of the `Î`s, which would cause it to decode as `Κ��ΦΑΛΗΞ��` when re-interpreted as UTF-8. Small changes like that make big differences.

Comment: Hmm... you're right. I'd just done a quick mangle and verified by eye, missing that.